# SQL query to find a specific value for all records

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
12345;01;Y
12345;02;Y
12345;03;Y
22222;01;Y
22222;02;Y
22222;03;N
33333;01;N
44444;01;Y
```

Need help in writing a SQL query to find all the records with value = 'Y' based on col1.For Eg output select Col1 should give the output as 12345 and 44444 [ not 22222 and 33333 as the col3 contains 'N' for them ]

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Add a where condition with the column value as 'Y'. You should post the query you have tried so far before asking any help.

Comment: use the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need `col1` where all values of col3 should be Y

```
select col1
from demo
group by col1
having count(*) = sum(Col3 = 'Y')
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76aa85/1)

Or if there can be only 2 possible values for col3 like `Y/N` then you can simplify your `having` clause as

```
having sum(Col3 = 'N') = 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76aa85/2)

Comment: Possibly to clarify, this relies on the outcome of `true` to be 1 and `false` to be 0, i.e. this could be expanded as `sum(case when Col3 = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: Sorry , but sum is not  possible on non numeric columns

Comment: @kavanabangalore As complete expression stated by **StuartLC** this means when you put a conditional clause in `sum(a = b)` for mysql only you will get the boolean result and like true/false and these values will be summed up so this * sum is not possible on non numeric columns* isn't valid anymore and you can get you conditional count by putting an expression in `sum` function

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING MAX(Col3) = MIN(Col3) AND MAX(Col3) = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
select distinct col1
from mytable
where col3='Y'
and col1 not in (select distinct col1 from mytable where col3='N')
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution using the difference

```
select distinct col1 from demo where col1 not in 
(select col1 from demo where col3='N')
```

Comment: I did not see the solution of sorineatza before posting. I agree with him