# PASS and FAIL records same test

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL rookie here. I tried searching but couldn't find this scenario.

For a particular exam students can have multiple records (Pass, Fail, No-Show, Dropped).

```
results table

Student_ID  Exam_ID    Status     Time_stamp

   1          A       Passed      2018-05-01
   2          A       Failed      2018-05-01
   2          A       Passed      2018-05-05  
   3          A       No-Show     2018-05-01
   3          A       Failed      2018-05-05
   4          A       Passed      2018-05-01
   4          A       Failed      2018-05-25
```

How can I structure my SQL query to show provide a list of students who have passed and if they haven't passed show the latest status by date.

For example in the sample data student_id 1 = passed, student_id 2 = passed (one pass record = passed) and student_id 3 = failed (no pass records, failed comes after no-show), student_id 4 = passed (one pass record on the exam = pass, ignore later fail)

So far I've tried this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE Status = "Passed"
```

But this obviously doesn't include the status of not-passed.

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Check out the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Why would a student take an exam again when they have already passed?

Comment: if we assume that if you pass an exam you don't repeat it (as @GordonLinoff notes) you can just take the maximum timestamp for each exam and each student to get your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using `union all`:

```
select r.*
from results r
where r.status = 'Passed'
union all
select t.*
from results r
where not exists (select 1 
                  from results r2
                  where r2.student_id = r.student_id and
                        r2.exam_id = r.exam_id and
                        r2.status = 'Passed'
                 ) and
      r.time_stamp = (select max(r2.time_stamp
                      from results r2
                      where r2.student_id = r.student_id and
                            r2.exam_id = r.exam_id 
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks approach worked for me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The below link is almost same. Use some tactics and you will get your answer

[SQL query to find a specific value for all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483770/sql-query-to-find-a-specific-value-for-all-records)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using RANK:

```
SELECT student_id, exam_id, status, time_stamp
FROM
(
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) AS rnk
FROM t
) sub
WHERE status = 'Passed'
OR (rnk = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM t t2
     WHERE status = 'Passed'
     AND t2.student_id = sub.student_id))
```

So the logic is: take the records where the status is passed OR (1) the test is the most recent for the student AND (2) the student does not have a passing test.

Answer (score 0):

An optimized version

`with t (Student_ID,  Exam_ID,    Status,     Time_stamp) as
(
select 1,          'A',       'Passed',      '2018-05-01' union all
select 2,          'A',       'Failed',      '2018-05-01' union all
select 2,          'A',       'Passed',      '2018-05-05' union all
select 3,          'A',       'No-Show',     '2018-05-01' union all
select 3,          'A',       'Failed',      '2018-05-05' union all
select 4,          'A',       'Passed',      '2018-05-01' union all
select 4,          'A',       'Failed',      '2018-05-25')
select * from (select *,row_number() over(PARTITION BY student_id,exam_id order by 
   case when status='Passed' then 1 
        when status='Failed' then 2
        when status='No-Show' then 3 end, time_stamp desc) r from t) result where r=1`